# How to fix oracle PL/SQL: ORA-00909: invalid number of argumentsCompilation failed,line 8 (13:53:12)

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-apex

I am creating a procedure with the following code in Oracle Apex
create or replace Procedure weekely_report

```
(W_start IN weekely_report.StartDate%TYPE, W_end IN
weekely_report.EndDate%TYPE)
IS
BEGIN
UPDATE weekely_report
   SET commission_amount = Sales_Amount*Com_Rate
 where (StartDate-EndDate) = (w_start- W_end);

SELECT concat('New Commission amount of',ID,' is
',commission_amount,' dollars,
is equal to',commission_amount,'% of the total sale amount of ',Sales_Amount,' dollars.')

COMMIT;
END;
```

But When I execute this, It give following error

> Compilation failed,line 8 (13:53:12) PL/SQL: ORA-00909: invalid number
> of argumentsCompilation failed,line 8 (13:53:12) PL/SQL: SQL Statement
> ignored

But the number of arguments is already completed, I checked twice.

Comment: Your select statement is invalid. It is allowed in Mysql. I think there is the issue.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I think select statement has no issue

Comment: In Oracle you cannot run any select without dual table.

Comment: @RamiFar - it does; as well as the `concat()` call having too many arguments, you have no `from` clause (and no *into* clause).

Comment: _" I think select statement has no issue"_  Oracle disagrees. Guess where my money is.  In oracle, a SELECT statement _must_  select FROM something.  If the data being SELECTed is not coming from a table or view (that is, it is just selecting the results of a function) then that is what oracle provides the DUAL table for .  It is a dummy table to be the target of the FROM clause when there is nothing else.

Comment: Besides the missing FROM clause in Oracle the [concat function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions040.htm#SQLRF00619) takes *exactly 2 parameters*, yours has 8. You can nest them so you have *concat(concat(cancat(...))))))* or convert to the [concatenation operator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Concatenation-Operator.html#GUID-08C10738-706B-4290-B7CD-C279EBC90F7E) (||). **Words of Wisdom:**  Do not argue with the compiler it wins every time.  Your job is to figure out what is wrong, not to declare the compiler incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle's [`concat()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CONCAT.html) only takes two arguments. You could nest calls:

```
SELECT concat(concat(concat(....
```

but that gets messy and hard to manage. it's simpler to user the concatenation operator `||`:

```
SELECT 'New Commission amount of ' || ID || ' is ' || commission_amount
  || ' dollars, is equal to ' || commission_amount || '% of the total sale amount of '
  || Sales_Amount || ' dollars.'
```

Your % looks like it should be a calculation, incidentally.

However, in Oracle you have to select *from* something, which in this case could be the table you just updated if your where condition identifies a single row; though a condition based on the number of days between two dates doesn't seem likely to do that - maybe that should be looking for matching start and end dates, rather than the size of the range? Then it might be unique. But in PL/SQL you also have to select *into* something such as a local variable or OUT parameter.

You could perhaps use [the `returning into` clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/RETURNING-INTO-clause.html) in your update statement instead.

It isn't clear what you expect to happen to that generated string though.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to add "from DUAL" to your SELECT statement. After that, you have to store the result into a variable using INTO clause. Finally, in Oracle, the CONCAT function will only allow you to concatenate two values together. If you want to concatenate more values than two, you can nest multiple CONCAT function calls.

For example:

SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT('A', 'B'),'C')
FROM dual;
Result: 'ABC'

Using pipe || is a more comfortable solution.